# How to display Popup message when installing an android app new version ? installing from GooglePlay

Tags: android, deployment, popup, installation, message

I want to display a pop-up message when user installs app from GooglePlay and show a text stating the new version replacing the old app and any other comment needed (e.g. like re-starting services manually), how to do it ? is there even a way to have OK/Cancel buttons (OK continue con install, Cancel abort install) ? Thank very much all in advance.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. If the user has chosen to allow automatic updates on your app, the update could occur at any point, and you do *not* want to be displaying a UI in the middle of something else that the user is doing.

Comment: I see, but I have seen this behavior in apps like Facebook, the kind of notice stating newer version x will replace old version and I need to display same behavior

Comment: You can show a pop-up telling your users that there is a new version of the current app available to update. Please see if [this](https://github.com/jrvansuita/CheckNewAppVersionAvailable) provides you the solution.